# Golang CSRF save template field in struct

Tags: http, go, webserver, csrf, mux

I am trying to make a simple webserver an decided to use [bone](https://github.com/go-zoo/bone) for my routes and [Gorilla csrf](https://github.com/gorilla/csrf) for csrf. The problem I am having is that I cannot save the csrf.TemplateField(req) in a struct to use in a template.

Imports:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"

    "github.com/go-zoo/bone"
    "github.com/gorilla/csrf"
)
```

Struc:

```
type Input struct {
    Title     string
    Name      string
    csrfField template.HTML // Error here: Undefined "text/template".HTML
}
```

Handler Code:

```
func RootHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    temp, _ := template.ParseFiles("site/index.html")
    head := Input{Title: "test", csrf.TemplateTag: csrf.TemplateField(req)}
    temp.Execute(rw, head)
}
```

I have tried changing the template.HTML type to string and then I got an error with csrf.TemplateField(req):

> unknown field 'csrf.TemplateTag' in struct literal of type Input

So can anybody help? Am I using the wrong type?

Comment: Change csrf.TemplateTag to csrfField. Make sure csrf.TemplateField(req) is type template.HTML

Comment: @Godfrey Thank you I changed csrf.Template Tag to CSRFField and in the struc I changed csrfField to CSRFField

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HTML` type is declared in "html/template" . Import "html/template" instead of "text/template".

The template engine ignores unexported fields. [Export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the field name by starting the name with an uppercase character.

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "net/http"
    "html/template"

    "github.com/go-zoo/bone"
    "github.com/gorilla/csrf"
)
Struc:

type Input struct {
    Title     string
    Name      string
    CSRFField template.HTML 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the second sentence of text/template documentation:

```
To generate HTML output, see package html/template, which has the same 
interface as this package but automatically secures HTML output against 
certain attacks.
```

text/template does not have an HTML method, thus you are receiving an undefined error.

Happy coding.